# Spring Cloud OpenFeign Calls Resulting in 400 Error

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign

When deploying an application with a Docker host network mode in our online environment, we have microservices A and B. Each server hosts only one instance of microservices A and B. When there are multiple instances of microservices A and B on different servers, we encounter occasional 400 errors when instance A, using OpenFeign, calls instance B on another server. However, these errors do not occur when instance A calls instance B on the same server. Some of the interfaces that result in 400 errors are parameterless. Our service discovery is done through Eureka, registering instances by IP. Currently, we lack the means and methods for tracing the call chain. Could you please provide some good strategies and approaches for troubleshooting this issue?

We have implemented the feign.RequestInterceptor interface on the client side to inspect the parameters and request headers being sent. On the server side, we are using filters to log the request parameters and headers. However, we are encountering a 400 error that is different from the usual ones. The issue is that the request is being terminated before the parameters can be logged by the filter, and the response does not specify which parameters are missing.

Comment: Can you share the issue details?